# Spring initializr not showing activiti dependency

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create spring-boot project for activiti but it is not showing activiti dependency.
How can I know that with which springboot version,activiti version is mapped?

[Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're refererring to [Activiti](https://www.activiti.org/), this is not included in the Spring Initializr so you will need to include this manually yourself.

1. Go through the Spring Initializr setup
2. Generate and download the code to your machine
3. Add the Activiti dependency to your POM or Gradle file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

4. Add the H2 dependency for database (don't use this in production):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.183</version>
</dependency>
```

I haven't used Activiti before but this is based on their [Spring Boot documentation](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#springSpringBoot).

Comment: I am referring same. ${activiti.version} is not resolving.

Comment: Got it - I would try using the latest version @Sanjay. This looks to be 6.0.0 judging by Maven. I've updated my answer, you can read more here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic/6.0.0

Comment: So the same thing I recommended you do?

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot 2 doesn't have activiti anymore.
Manually need to add activiti dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```